# Switch Sound Button in Unity Javascript code

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to figure out how to use "sound off" and "sound on" images to control game sound. The code below displays a sound button but when you click on it, it mutes the sounds but adds a shaded circle over the button.

I would like some guide or how to make it switch from a sound on to a sound off image button as I am new to Unity.

Image File Names: SoundButton.psd and WhiteCircle.psd

```
var whiteCircle : GameObject;
var numberOfTouch : int = 0;
private var a : float = 1;
function Start() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SoundBoolean") == 0) {
        //check whether the sound is included, if turned on, then play sound.
        numberOfTouch = 0;
        whiteCircle.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).enabled = false;
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SoundBoolean") == 1) {
        //check whether the sound is included, if turned off, then turn off the sound.
        numberOfTouch = 1;
        whiteCircle.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).enabled = true;
    }
}
function OnMouseDown () {
    if (a <= 0) {
        if (numberOfTouch == 0) {
            //completely turn off the music.
            a = 1;
            numberOfTouch = 1;
            gameObject.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
            whiteCircle.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).enabled = true;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SoundBoolean", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
    if (a <= 0) {
        if (numberOfTouch == 1) {
            //a fully turn on the music.
            a = 1;
            numberOfTouch = 0;
            whiteCircle.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).enabled = false;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SoundBoolean", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
}
function Update() {
    if (a >= 0) {
        a -= 0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to add more unity-related tags, ("unity3d, unity5, etc" for example) to question, since unityscript tag is pretty small, and people on "javascript" and "audio" tags rather dont have requiered specific knowlege.

Comment: Thanks @IdeaMan done that.

Comment: Can you tell me what is not working right now for you? What behaviour do you see in your program?

Comment: @Joetjah thansk for reply. Basically, when I click on the sound, it mutes the sound which is fine but a circle is placed over the sound button to depict OFF state. I just want to use an off sound button image - see [image](http://snag.gy/8QGWn.jpg)

Comment: As you're new to Unity, I think you should try Unity's UI feature. It helps you to create many UI elements including buttons. There is a tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood correctly, you're looking for something to change the sprite on an object you have. I'm not testing my code or anything, but perhaps it can help you solve your problem.

```
var sprite1 : Sprite; // Drag your first sprite here
var sprite2 : Sprite; // Drag your second sprite here
var spriteRenderer : SpriteRenderer = whiteCircle.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer); 

var whiteCircle : GameObject;
var numberOfTouch : int = 0;
private var a : float = 1;
function Start() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SoundBoolean") == 0) {
        //check whether the sound is included, if turned on, then play sound.
        numberOfTouch = 0;
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite2;
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SoundBoolean") == 1) {
        //check whether the sound is included, if turned off, then turn off the sound.
        numberOfTouch = 1;
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite1;
    }
}
function OnMouseDown () {
    if (a <= 0) {
        if (numberOfTouch == 0) {
            //completely turn off the music.
            a = 1;
            numberOfTouch = 1;
            gameObject.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
            spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SoundBoolean", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
    if (a <= 0) {
        if (numberOfTouch == 1) {
            //a fully turn on the music.
            a = 1;
            numberOfTouch = 0;
            spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite2;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SoundBoolean", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
}
function Update() {
    if (a >= 0) {
        a -= 0.1;
    }
}
```

Basically, add two sprite points to where you can drag your image files, then replace the sprite on a certain spriterenderer (instead of turning it on and off).

Comment: tried it and getting error:

ERROR1 - SoundButton.js(1,8): BCE0043: Unexpected token: Sprite.
ERROR2 - SoundButton.js(2,8): BCE0043: Unexpected token: Sprite.
ERROR3 - SoundButton.js(3,9): BCE0043: Unexpected token: SpriteRenderer.

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover I editted my post. I used C# instead of UnityScript, my bad.

Comment: I ran into another issue after making following [changes](http://snag.gy/ELJnk.jpg).

SoundButton and SoundButtonOff is teh filename of each button image.

ERROR: SoundButton.js(2,15): BCE0018: The name 'SoundButtonOff' does not denote a valid type ('not found'). Did you mean 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod'?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover It seems you don't understand the syntax of UnityScript and how coding in this language works. I suggest you read up on some basic tutorials about coding. Why it isn't working for you: A Sprite is a standard class UnityScript knows about. When you type `var sprite1 : Sprite`, you're basically telling the compiller to create a Sprite object with the name sprite1. When you change the code to `var sprite1 : SoundButton`, there should be an object class named SoundButton so Unity knows what you are talking about when you declare such an object.

Comment: yea I was able to get that sorted after doing some readings, see [here](http://snag.gy/LvpAd.jpg).

On testing, i am getting another error:
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable spriteRenderer of SoundButton has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the spriteRenderer variable of the SoundButton script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer.set_sprite (UnityEngine.Sprite value)

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover Yes, that is because the code tries to fetch the Sprite from the `whiteCircle` object. Which you haven't assigned yet, according to your screenshot. `whiteCircle` should be the object on which the sprite is placed. This would be the button object.